# Can't add contributors due to seat limits despite downgradign to free

Tags: github, github-organizations

I need to add users to an organization on github.
Previously, we couldn't add more users because of a paid subscription. I've tried downgrading to free, but because we paid a yearly bill, functionally we are still a subscribed organization for a few months. There doesn't appear to be anyway to even cancel that.

There doesn't appear to be a way to cut off the subscription even if we have already paid the bill until it ends, and whenever we try to add anyone it simply informs us that the seats are full.
I'm starting to think the only solution might be to setup a temporary faux-organization that we move the projects we're currently working on over to and then back once our subscription expires.